# Does more HDD platters and heads mean hotter drives?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a self-built NAS with 2 different drives, one is a WD Blue 2TB (WD20EZRZ) and a Seagate Ironwolf 8TB.  I did some research and it seems like the WD has 2 platters and 4 heads, and the Ironwolf has 7 platters and 14 heads.  Does this mean that more HDD platters mean more heat generated?  It seems like my HDD status seem to confirm this:

CrystalDiskInfo temps:

WD Blue: 38-40C

Ironwolf 8TB: 41-45C (sometimes it gets to 47C on a very hot day)

Comment: Pretty much 100% of the power drawn results in heat. So you can just look up which drive uses more power while in operation.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that more HDD platters mean more heat generated?

Only because there's typically a R/W head assembly per platter surface.  (The platter has two surfaces.)

The platters are rotated at a fixed speed, and the inertia generates a flywheel effect, so the heat given off by the spindle motor should be constant.
Read/write activity will likely require seeks, and the voice-coil motor of the actuator (that moves the entire R/W head assembly) would be a variable source of heat, depending on the number and duration of seek operations.

Increase the number of R/W heads and you have more mass in the head assembly to move.
That requires either a larger voice-coil motor to be installed or the motor has to perform more work.
Either way more heat could be generated compared to a drive with fewer heads.

---

Beware that your question is based on an observation with dubious conditions.
Are these two HDDs accessed identically (not likely since they have different capacities)?
Are these two HDDs mounted in the enclosure with identical ambient conditions (e.g. do they have the same amount of cooling, or is one mounted above the other, or is one mounted closer to a fan)?

IOW you do not have a controlled experiment (to accurately compare temperatures), and are formulating a question to focus on just one aspect while there are many unknown conditions.

Comment: Also, more platters means more weight. All other things being the same (friction coefficients, motor efficiency, etc) the heat generated (quantity of energy loss through heat) by the constant rotation of the platters would be higher; linearly I believe.